# convert integer into decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, decimal

the two columns in a table are both INT, SA.SalesQuantity and SA.RefundQuantity

I want to work out a variance between 2107 and 2016 using case statements as in below:

```
(SUM(CASE WHEN SA.FISCALYEAR = 2017 AND SA.FISCALWEEK = 22 
THEN SA.SalesQuantity-SA.RefundQuantity END ) 
/ SUM(CASE WHEN SA.FISCALYEAR = 2016 AND SA.FISCALWEEK = 22 
THEN SA.SalesQuantity-SA.RefundQuantity END ))-1 
AS 'SaleQTY_Var'
```

How would I get my result returned as a decimal and not an INT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Int/Int = Int` so change either *numerator* or *denominator* as Decimal value to get the result with decimal value. I have multiplied the numerator with `1.0` to convert it as decimal

```
(SUM(CASE WHEN SA.FISCALYEAR = 2017 AND SA.FISCALWEEK = 22 
THEN SA.SalesQuantity-SA.RefundQuantity * 1.0 END ) 
/ 
SUM(CASE WHEN SA.FISCALYEAR = 2016 AND SA.FISCALWEEK = 22 
THEN SA.SalesQuantity-SA.RefundQuantity END ))-1 
AS 'SaleQTY_Var'
```

Comment: This worked perfect, sort of follows a bit of logic I would be used to with Excel, where you can use *0 to convert text to a number etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simply the convert the value *after* the calculation:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 4)
        (SUM(CASE WHEN SA.FISCALYEAR = 2017 AND SA.FISCALWEEK = 22 
THEN SA.SalesQuantity - SA.RefundQuantity END )*1.0 
/ SUM(CASE WHEN SA.FISCALYEAR = 2016 AND SA.FISCALWEEK = 22 
THEN SA.SalesQuantity - SA.RefundQuantity END )) - 1 
       ) AS SaleQTY_Var
```

Answer (score 0):

And another approach with `CAST` method for converting one of the operands to decimal type

```
CAST(
    (SUM(CASE WHEN SA.FISCALYEAR = 2017 AND SA.FISCALWEEK = 22 
         THEN SA.SalesQuantity-SA.RefundQuantityEND) AS DECIMAL) 
/ 
SUM(CASE WHEN SA.FISCALYEAR = 2016 AND SA.FISCALWEEK = 22 
    THEN SA.SalesQuantity-SA.RefundQuantity END )) - 1 
AS 'SaleQTY_Var'
```